# MSE and MSR in regression question

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model, sums-of-squares

> In a small-scale regression study, five observations on $Y$ were
>   obtained corresponding to $X = 1,4,10, 11$, and $14$. Assume that
>   $\sigma=0.6,B_0=5,B_1=3$
>
> a. What are the expected values off MSR and MSE here?
>
> b. For determining whether or not a regression relation exists, would
>   it has been better or worse to have made the five observations at $X
>  = 6,7, 8, 9$, and $10$? Why? Would the same answer apply if the principal purpose were to estimate the mean response for $X = 8$?
>   Discuss.

$$Y_i=B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i$$
$$\hat{Y_i}=\hat{B_0}+\hat{B_1}X_i$$

$$MSR=\sum(\hat{Y_i}-\overline{Y})^2$$

$$MSE=\frac{\sum (Y_i-\hat{Y_i)}^2}{n-2}=\frac{\sum(B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i-\hat{B_0}-\hat{B_1}X_i)^2}{n-2}$$

I'm still doesn't understand what they want, they want
$$E(MSE);E(MSR)$$?

What do they mean by expected values?

Comment: What is your understanding of the "expected values" requested in (a)?

Comment: @whuber I've done some exercises where calculated values of MSR and MSE, but the $Y$ values were already given. I know that $$\hat{Y_i}=\hat{B_0}+\hat{B_1}X_i$$ where $\hat{Y_i}$ is the fitted value, in this case I need the values of $Y_i$, I need to consider the random error? $$Y_i=B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i$$

Comment: The question does not concern calculated values: it explicitly asks for *expected values.*  That is intended in the sense of expectations of random variables.  MSR and MSE are both random because they depend on the random variables $\epsilon_i$.  Thus, you can answer this question only by making assumptions about the expectations (and, it will turn out, variances and covariances) of the $\epsilon_i$ and knowing the formulas for MSE and MSR in terms of the $\epsilon_i$. Since $\epsilon_i$ can be computed as $Y_i - (B_0+B_1X_i)$, start with formulas in terms of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Comment: @whuber I still can not understand this exercise, because if I do not need to calculate values. Why were given the values of the observations and parameters?

Comment: Often, unnecessary extra information is provided in questions either to make them easier for those with limited algebra skills or to distract those who do not understand the concepts at all.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question any more after your latest edits.  If you wish to post an answer to your original question, then please do so as an *answer,* not by changing the question.  BTW, what calculation supports your answer to (b)?

Comment: @whuber Actually I was looking in the book I'm using and $$\sigma^2(Y_{h(new)})=\sigma^2$$ then theoretically choose any of the intervals would be indifferent

Comment: That conclusion is incorrect, however.  You need to look at the formula for the standard error of $B_1$.

Comment: @whuber $$\sigma(\hat{B_1})=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2}}=\frac{0.6}{\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2}}$$ 
for the case where $X=(1,4,10,11,14)$ we have that $\sigma(\hat{B_1})=0.05619515$
and for the case where $X=(6,7,8,9,10)$ $\sigma(B_1)=0.1897367$, then the first set is better I think. But why I need to look $\sigma(\hat{B_1})$?

Answer (score 1):

$$Y_i=B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i$$
$$\hat{Y_i}=\hat{B_0}+\hat{B_1}X_i$$

a) $$E[MSE]=E[\frac{\sum(Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2}{n-2}]=\sigma^2=0.6^2$$
$$E[MSR]=E[\sum(\hat{Y_i}-\overline{Y})^2]=\sigma^2+B_1\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2=1026.36$$

b)
$$\sigma(\hat{B_1})=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2}}=\frac{0.6}{\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2}}$$ 
for the case where $X=(1,4,10,11,14)$ we have that $\sigma(\hat{B_1})=0.05619515$
and for the case where $X=(6,7,8,9,10)$ $\sigma(B_1)=0.1897367$, then the first set is better I think.

But why I need to look $\sigma(\hat{B_1})$?

Is there any difference if it were estimating the mean response for X = 8?